# Bootstrap for a project

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Stack Overflow, I am trying to put 2 text types inside of a input in bootstrap. Is this possible and if so how do i go about it. at the moment I have one placeholder text inside of the input but i also need the title to be inside of the input. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHxo3.png)

how can i make it so i have the title and the placeholder text inside of the input field

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4 border-0" placeholder="Anrede*">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4 border-0" placeholder="Vorname*">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4 border-0" placeholder="Email*">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4 border-0" placeholder="Telefon*">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/9bvjta3r/

```
input:focus ~ .floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label{
  top: 8px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
```